# How to chage default website icon in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, icons

I need to change this icon:

[image]

I already changed the icon in the properties of the project, and proceeded to build the project:

[image]

But the icon doesn't change. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Did u try to force reload (i mean clearing the cache). You can doit with ctrl+f5 on browser.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it doesn't change the icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But the icon doesn't change. Is there anything else I need to do?

If you want to set the icon in `properties`.Be sure there is **only one** `.ico` file named `favicon` in your project,then build the project.You need press both `Ctrl`+`F5` in the browser to refresh the website.

Another way is:

My `.ico` file located in the `wwwroot` folder,so I just add the following code to the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    //add this line..
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/YourIconName.ico" sizes="32x32">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option (adding the link) worked for me